# django static files

Tags: django, static, django-templates

I have in my urls.py line:

```
if settings.DEBUG==True:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_DOC_ROOT})
    )
```

In my settings file something like this:

```
STATIC_DOC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'static').replace('\\','/')
```

And when I go to / in my page everything work just great. And when I click a link from / to anther page I don't have CSS applied because of 404 error. He tries to load a CSS file from that URL.

```
http://localhost:8000/show/sth/static/style.css
```

Here is my urls.py for this method

```
(r'^show/(?P<subject>[^/]+)/(?P<title>[^/]+)$','show'),
```

I have url /links and css works just in this one template it does not work. It seems that these parameters messing something up. Any suggestions why this fails?
Here is my template code:

```
{% extends "szkielet.html" %}
{% block tresc %}
    <div id="content">
        <div class="post">
            <h2 class="title">{{ notatka.tytul }}</h2>
                <p class="meta"><span class="author">{{ notatka.user.name }}</span> <span class="date">July 07, 2010</span>&nbsp;<span class="links"><a href="#" title="">Comments</a></span></p>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p>{{ notatka.tresc }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Szkielet.html - it is my base

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Perfect Blemish      by Free CSS Templates</title>
<link href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
```

Here is part responsible for CSS it is only one style sheet .

Comment: I guess you have a base html to extend all the templates from. have you forgotten to extend on this page.

Comment: I have extend part. Problem is that in that one template the css is not working because of bad path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL's could potentially be set to override the static url path but that's not the case here! So your URL conf doesn't have anything to do with this.

The core problem is that your template is rendering an incorrect URL: `http://localhost:8000/show/sth/static/style.css` should be `http://localhost:8000/static/style.css` correct?

Show us your template since that seems to be the problem. Sounds to me like you just have a relative URL set for your CSS instead of absolute or `/static/style.css`

What is your `{{ media_url }}`? It's supposed to be absolute, and begin with a `/`

Comment: with urls you are right in 100% it is exactly how it behaves and how it should behave. I added code in my first post

Comment: You gotta post the templates that have the CSS file links

Comment: so make sure your media_url is not a relative url. Either make sure it starts with a `/` or contains the full path to your media `http://localhost:8000/static/`

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I forget to add / in MEDIA_URL at the beggining . When i add it now everything works perfectly thank Yuji one more time